# How to change NameSpaceUri at runtime of a WebService in order to point it to a different endPoint?

Tags: web-services, spring, jax-ws, spring-ws

I am using `org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` to configure my client WebService but I cannot change the interface targetNameSpaceUri to make it point to a different URL.

Using `<property name="namespaceUri" value="http://localhost:9191/my/" />` is not doing it.

My config looks like this

```
    <bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="http://localhost:9191/my/" />          
        <property name="serviceName" value="my" />
        <property name="portName" value="myPort" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="br.com.asis.my.myService" />           
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://localhost:9191/my/?wsdl" />
        <property name="lookupServiceOnStartup" value="false" />
    </bean>     
    <bean id="myHandler" class="br.com.cflex.asis.my.myHandler">
        <property name="service"            ref="myService"></property>
    </bean>
```

And I have the br.com.asis.my.myService Interface with this annotations.

```
@WebService(name = "myService")
public interface myService {

/**
 * 
 * @param message
 * @return
 *     returns java.lang.String
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "Sendmessages")
@WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "Sendmessages", className = "br.com.asis.my.Sendmessages")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "SendmessageResponse", className = "br.com.asis.my.SendmessageResponse")
public String sendmessages(
    @WebParam(name = "message")
    message message);
```

}

But changing

```
<property name="namespaceUri" value="http://localhost:9191/my/" />
```

in my Spring config, doesn't change the Service URI, I would like to be able to change that and have it applied to all my client Service Interfaces, instead of having to use Annotations like this

```
@WebService(name = "myService", targetNamespace="http://localhost:9191/myService/")
```

Is it possible ?